# Why are corners not detected in images with chessboard fiducials?

Tags: ros, opencv, tod-detecting

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using pose_estimator in tod_training for creating a training base, I wonder why sometimes the pose estimation fails. On fat_free_milk from [tod kinect training data](http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/tod_kinect_bags/training/) pose could be estimated on all of its images.

[image: image description]

This might also be an OpenCV issue since the underlying [cv::findChessboardCorners](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findchessboardcorners#findChessboardCorners) in OpenCV does not return any corners. How come?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9820/why-are-corners-not-detected-in-images-with-chessboard-fiducials?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-04-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-05-05**:
Thanks for your suggestion.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-05**:
You might want to reword the question headline. It doesn't read as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some things to try:

1. Bring the object closer; maybe the chessboard is too small.
2. Mess with the lighting; even with a black-and-white image, things are tricky.
3. Make sure you're giving OpenCV the correct chessboard size; it wants the number of rows/cols, not the number of corners, IIRC.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-22**:
Sorry for the misunderstanding. The chessboard was detected in about 80% of all pictures similar to the one in my question, *WITHOUT* incorporating your suggestions. I hope I can try whether using your suggestion pushes the success rate to 100%. Need the laboratory though for this.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-21**:
If you think I've answered your question, you should mark it answered. Karma karma karma!

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-21**:
Thanks for the suggestions. Using a larger chessboard seems to be a prospective idea to try next time. It worked in 80% of all test cases, so I think the general configuration was correct. In my case, lighting should not be changed too much. The OpenCV mailing list shows similar issues.